# EXCEL: How to add background header color in excel; exported using PHP?

Tags: php, css, excel

I'm generating an excel sheet using PHP. I want to add colors to the headers.

I tried something like this:

```
$filename = "Stack_Rank_ReportV2_(".$fromdate."_".$todate.").xls";
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");      
        header("Expires: 0");
        echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                <td style='background-color:#f00;'>header</td>
                </tr>
              </table>";
        $head_row = "EmployeeId"."\t";
        $head_row .= "EmployeeName"."\t";
        $head_row .= "Actual Designation"."\t";
        $head_row .= "Cluster"."\t";

   echo $head_row;
```

But it messes up from entire excel sheet. Doesn't work. Couldn't find anything on the web either.
Help me out please.

Comment: for only the first column or the whole columns in the first line ?

Comment: just the first column in the first row @MohammedYassineCHABLI

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

You have to add just the attribute **bgcolor**  and then play it with your own way .

```
<?php

$filename = "Stack_Rank_ReportV.xls";
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Expires: 0");
echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr bgcolor='red'>
                <td>header</td>
                </tr>
              </table>";
$head_row = "EmployeeId"."\t";
$head_row .= "EmployeeName"."\t";
$head_row .= "Actual Designation"."\t";
$head_row .= "Cluster"."\t";

echo $head_row;
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work sir. It produces the same mess. Makes all the content just 1 block of text.